# Can I retrain a multiclass feat?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, multi-classing, retraining

Can I retrain a multiclass feat?  Furthermore can I retrain into a different multiclass feat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a [2008 post](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19655778/Retraining_multiclass_feats&post_num=5):

> Yes. See page 28 for the rules for retraining, and the restrictions on doing it.

A [different thread](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19605386/Retraining_multiclass_feats&post_num=4) has a better discussion:

> You can't retrain a feat if other feats need it as a pre-req. So if you have a multiclass feat AND a power swap feat, you need to retrain the power swap feat first and then the multiclass feat. You can never retrain a multiclass feat if you've take a multiclass paragon path, becuase that is unchangeable. Retraining one multiclass feat to another, or to anything else is fine as long as you have nothing else that requires the feat.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, multiclass feats can generally be retrained.

The retraining rules are on pg 87 of the *Rules Compendium*.  It notes that feats can be replaced with two exceptions:

1. If the feat is a prerequisite for any attribute the character currently has
2. If the feat is a feature of the character's class, paragon path or epic destiny.